# Помогите в создании правил для urlrewrite.php (Битрикс)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, битрикс

Помогите советом. В разных разделах сайта (/catalog/ и /articles/) стоят простые компоненты (bitrix:catalog.section + bitrix:catalog.element) и соответственно (bitrix:news.list + bitrix:news.detail).

Пытаюсь настроить ЧПУ. Вот мой urlrewrite.php

```html
<?
$arUrlRewrite = array(
    array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/rest/#",
        "RULE" => "",
        "ID" => "",
        "PATH" => "/bitrix/services/rest/index.php",
        "SORT" => "50",
    ),
    array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/articles/([a-zA-Z0-9\\\\.\\\\-_]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\\\\.\\\\-_]+)/?.*#",
        "RULE" => "SECTION_CODE=\$1&ELEMENT_CODE=\$2&\$3",
        "ID" => "",
        "PATH" => "/articles/detail.php",
        "SORT" => "100",
    ),
    array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/([^/]+?)/([^/]+?)/\\??(.*)#",
        "RULE" => "SECTION_CODE=\$1&ELEMENT_CODE=\$2&\$3",
        "ID" => "bitrix:catalog.element",
        "PATH" => "/catalog/detail.php",
        "SORT" => "200",
    ),
    array(
        "CONDITION" => "#^/([^/]+?)/\\??(.*)#",
        "RULE" => "SECTION_CODE=\$1&\$2",
        "ID" => "bitrix:catalog.section",
        "PATH" => "/catalog/index.php",
        "SORT" => "300",
    ),
);
?>
```

В данный момент при попытке открыть "Новость детально" перекидывает на "Элемент каталога детально" Чую что то наворотил с правилами регулярки.

ЧПУ настройки компонентов следующие (лишние параметры вырезал):

```
$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
"bitrix:news.detail", 
".default", 
array(
    "DETAIL_URL" => "#SECTION_CODE#/#ELEMENT_CODE#/",
    "ELEMENT_CODE" => $_REQUEST["ELEMENT_CODE"],
    "ELEMENT_ID" => "",
    "IBLOCK_TYPE" => "articles",
    "IBLOCK_URL" => "/articles/"
),
false
```

Comment: ну так уточните CONDINION для элемента каталога у вас он не специфицирован для страниц только каталога.

Comment: Уточнил вот так: "CONDITION" => "#^/catalog/([^/]+?)/([^/]+?)/\\??(.*)#" - правила вообще перестали работать. Неверно уточнил?

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться правилами в urlrewrite.php чего нельзя сделать с помощью настроек ЧПУ в параметрах компонента? Если /catalog/ и /articles/ разные директории и в них подключены нужные компоненты просто настройте ЧПУ в параметрах компонентов.

Comment: При стандартной настройке ЧПУ через компонент они перекрывают друг друга, и при детальном просмотре новости, обращается к каталогу. Я потому и начал ковырять urlrewrite, что при стандартной настройке выводит вышеупомянутую ошибку.